# Letting $I_j$ be the indicator r.v. for the $j$th jumper setting a recording, prove $I_j,I_i$ are independent.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, solution-verification

> Athletes compete one at a time at the high jump. Let $X_j$ be how high
> the $j$th jumper jumped, with $X_1, X_2,...$ i.i.d. with a continuous
> distribution. We say that the $j$th jumper set a record if $X_j$ is
> greater than all of $X_{j-1},...,X_1$. Find the variance of the number of records among the first $n$ jumpers.

Letting $I_j$ be the indicator r.v. for the $j$th jumper setting a recording, I want to know if $I_j,I_i$ are independent.

Intuitively, I feel like if the 100th jumper set a record, that means the 100th jumper probably jumped very high, affecting the probability that the 101th jumper will set a record. Why is this intuition wrong? I know this is wrong because I did a combinatorial argument that showed independence. But I'm curious about the intuition part.

Comment: Your intuition that the $100$th jumper going higher than the previous $99$ jumpers would suggest it was a very high jump is a reasonable thought, but you could say that the $34$th jumper going higher than the previous $33$ and the next $66$ would also suggest that was a very high jump.  In fact, which of the first $100$ went highest should not affect how very high you think that jump must have been as they could have jumped in any order.

Answer (score 3):

Whether the $101$st jumper sets a record depends only on whether the height she achieves is greater than the $100$ previous heights. The probability for that (which is $\frac1{101}$ by symmetry) doesn’t depend on which of the $100!$ possible orders of the $100$ previous heights was realized. The fact that the $100$th jumper set a record doesn’t mean that he jumped  any higher than the best out of $100$ jumps would have been expected to be – all it means is that the best out of $100$ jumps happened to occur on the $100$th jump (with probability $\frac1{100}$).