Blitzstein, Problem number 7, Stat 110 Homework 4 Solutions, Fall 2011
chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/https://projects.iq.harvard.edu/sites/projects.iq.harvard.edu/files/stat110/files/strategic_practice_and_homework_4.pdf
Problem 7 of Homework 4
Athletes compete one at a time at the high jump. Let $X_j$ be how high the $j$th jumper jumped, with $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ i.i.d. with a continuous distribution. We say that the $j$th jumper set a record if $X_j$ is greater than all of $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_{j-1}$.
(a) Is the event “the 110th jumper sets a record” independent of the event “the 111th jumper sets a record”? Justify your answer by finding the relevant probabilities in the definition of independence and with an intuitive explanation.
Let $I_j$ be the indicator random variable for the $j$th jumper setting a record.
My query:
The solution begins by saying:
"Let $I_j$ be the indicator random variable for the $j$th jumper setting a record. By symmetry, $P(I_j = 1) = \frac{1}{j}$ (as all of the first $j$ jumps are equally likely to be the highest of those jumps)."
But why is the probability 1/j? I can understand this intuitively. But how does one prove it without invoking symmetry, as the author has. My primary doubt is, if $X_j$ needs to be maximal, compared to all other jumps, then we need to find P($I_j$ = 1).
How do we choose our event in this case from a continuous distribution, which by definition has an infinite number of outcomes? We would need to consider a set that comprises an infinite number of j-tuples (each being an outcome of our experiment), each of which has a maximal element at the jth position. This is because the jumpers could jump any random distance, so all such outcomes need to be considered.
However, we have an infinite number of such j-tuples, how do I get a handle on that?
This same problem has been tackled elsewhere on stackexchange, but all of them invoke symmetry arguments to justify the answer, something I don't understand.

This question has already been answered I think?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4622841/letting-i-j-be-the-indicator-r-v-for-the-jth-jumper-setting-a-recording-pr?rq=1

No it is not. Sorry. I want to understand the proof of "1/j."

I have made the edits

You can define a random variable $Y_j:= \max_{1\leq i \leq j} X_i$. Then $\{ I_j=1 \}=\{ Y_j =X_j \}$.
Notice also that $ \cup_{\ell=1}^j \{ Y_j =X_\ell \} $ is the whole event space. Since $X_1,...,X_j$ are i.i.d, you have that $\mathbb{P}( Y_j=X_{\ell_1} )= \mathbb{P}( Y_j=X_{\ell_2} )$  for any $\ell_1,\ell_2\in \{ 1,...,j \}$. Since the random variables are continuous, you get that $\mathbb{P}(X_{\ell_1}=X_{\ell_2})=0$ for any distinct $\ell_1,\ell_2$.
This implies that $1= \sum_{\ell=1}^j\mathbb{P}(Y_j=X_\ell)$, and so $\mathbb{P}(Y_j=X_j)=\frac{1}{j}$.

Edit: I am adding a rigorous explanation, which might be too heavy handed. If any one knows a shorter solution, it might be best.
Anyways, we can enumerate the rationals $\{ q_n \}_{n=1}^\infty \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, and define $U_n:=[q_n,\infty)$ and $D_n:=(-\infty,q_n]$. The event that $Y_j=1$ can be written as
$$\{ Y_j=k\} =\cup_{n=1} \Big( \{ X_k\in U_n \}\bigcap \cap_{\ell\neq k}^j \{ X_\ell\in D_n \} \Big).  $$
Denote $E_n^{(k)}:=\Big( \{ X_k\in U_n \}\bigcap \cap_{\ell\neq k}^j \{ X_\ell\in D_n \} \Big)$ for any $1\leq k\leq j$. Then $\mathbb{P}(Y_j=k)= \lim_{N\to \infty} \mathbb{P}\Big( \cup_{n=1}^N E_n^{(k)} \Big)$. So it's enough to show each term does not depend on $k$. You can compute the probability of the finite union by exclusion-inclusion principle. From the inclusion-exclusion principle formula, you just need to show that the probability an intersection $E_{n_1}^{(k)}\cap ...\cap E_{n_m}^{(k)}$ does not depend on $k$. For any $n_1,...,n_m$, denote $\hat{q}:=\max \{q_{n_1},...,q_{n_m}\}$ and $\check{q}:=\max \{q_{n_1},...,q_{n_m}\}$.
Then
$$ \cap_{\ell=1}^m E_{n_\ell}^{(k)}=\{ X_k\in [\hat{q},\infty) \} \bigcap \cap_{\ell\neq k}^j \{  X_\ell\in (-\infty, \check{q}]  \}. $$
If the CDF of $X_1,...,X_j$ is $F$, then the last event has probability $\big( 1-F(\hat{q}) \big)\cdot F(\check{q})^{j-1}$. You can see that this does not depend on $k$.
This is a brute force approach to showing that for continuous i.i.d random variables, the probability that $\ell_1$ or $\ell_2$ is the maximal one is the same.

Random variables are function that map to real numbers, here you map the random variable Y to another random variable, how does this work?

@S_M A probability measure satisfies some axioms. It gives value 1 to the set of all possible events and is additive on disjoint sets. The event space here can be realized as infinite tuples of possible values for the $X_n$'s. I wanted to use the axioms on the measure to say $ \sum_{\ell=1}^j\mathbb{P}(Y_j=X_\ell)=1$. This needs some slight justification.

$Y_j$ is also a random variable. The same as how a maximum between two functions is itself a function. It assign to each point a unique value. I should mention, that for $I_j$ and $Y_j$ you can restrict yourself to the $j$-tuples corresponding to values of $X_1,...,X_j$.

Since $X_1, \ldots, X_j$ are i.i.d., you have that $P(Y_j = X_{\ell_1}) = P(Y_j = X_{\ell_2})$ for any $\ell_1, \ell_2 \in {1, \ldots, j}$.
@Keen-ameteur: How do you say this? This is where I am getting stuck. I can see this intuitively, but how do you partition the space? You can't even number the tuples, given their uncountableness.
